# sys.sp_reset_connection runs for up to 5 minutes

Tags: sql-server-2019, sqloledb, sp-reset-connection

`sys.sp_reset_connection` runs for up to 5 minutes on SQL Server 2019 CU13 [SQL1] .

At the same time other SQL Servers [SQL100..SQL200] that have linked server to [SQL1] are timing out:

> TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "SQL1" returned message "Client unable to establish connection"

What is causing the connectivity issue? Why is `sys.sp_reset_connection` running for so long and could it run faster?

Comment: How are you determining that `sp_reset_connection` takes 5 minutes? One of the tasks it does is rollback uncommitted transactions so that could take some time depending on the amount of data modifications.

Comment: `sp_reset_connection` isn't a real stored procedure. It's just a way for SQL Server to reset the connection settings, and can be signaled by the client within a TDS packet, commonly used in drivers that use connection pooling. How are you determining that `sp_reset_connection` is the issue? What else is going on on the server at the same time? Can you run `DBCC OPENTRAN` and `EXEC sp_who2` while this is happening?

Comment: I see in sp_whoisactive it's duration is 5 minutes

Comment: there are hundred of sp_reset_connection procs that run on a server at any given time. I  sp_whoisactive, shows  zero open_tran_count and hundred of application SQL Servers that access SQL1 and run the sp_reset_connection